# if statement in pyGTK

Tags: python, gtk

I am trying to make a basic calculator with python using gtk but I have a problem with the if statement. Here is the code :

```
import gtk
class PyApp(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp,self).__init__()
        self.set_title("Project")
        self.set_size_request(245,400)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        fixed = gtk.Fixed()
        self.label = gtk.Label("Welcome to my project!")
        fixed.put(self.label, 60, 40)
        self.lbl = gtk.Label("")
        fixed.put(self.lbl,60,200)
        entry = gtk.Entry()
        entry2 = gtk.Entry()
        self.char = gtk.Entry()
        fixed.put(self.char, 60 , 130)     
        fixed.put(entry, 60, 100)
        fixed.put(entry2, 60, 160)
        btn = gtk.Button("Click me")
        fixed.put(btn, 60, 200) 
        btn.connect("clicked", self.licked)
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.add(fixed)
        self.show_all()
        self.e = entry
        self.e2 = entry2
    def licked(self, widget):
        self.txt = self.e.get_text()
        self.ee2 = self.e2.get_text()
        if str(self.char.get_text()) == "*":
            c = str(int(self.txt) * int(self.ee2))
            self.lbl.set_text(c)
        elif str(self.char.get_text()) == "/":
            c = str(int(self.txt) / int(self.ee2))
            self.lbl.set_text(c)
        elif str(self.char.get_text()) == "+":
            c = str(int(self.txt) + int(self.ee2))
            self.lbl.set_text(c)
        elif str(self.char.get_text()) == "-":
            c = str(int(self.txt) - int(self.ee2))
            self.lbl.set_text(c) 
        else:
            self.lbl.set_text("Sorry plaese enter * or / or - or + !")
PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

When I run the program and input the three values (the char and num1 & num2)
the output after clicking the click me button is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the output is below the button '"Click me". To avoid this, drop down a `Label` like this:

```
fixed.put(self.lbl,60,240)
```